# Enumerate all paths of length 3 in a given tree T

Tags: algorithms, graphs, trees

Kind help with an algorithm or any refrence to enumerate all paths of length 3 in a given tree T in the shortest possible time.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting question. What did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Does length=3 refer to the number of vertices or edges?

Answer (score 1):

Let $T$ be a tree on $n$ vertices. Root $T$ in an arbitrary vertex $r$ and let $p(v)$ denote the parent of vertex $v \neq r$ in $T$. For $v \in V$, let $C(v)$ denote the children of $v$ in $T$.

A path $\langle v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4 \rangle$ of length $3$ in $T$ is of exactly one of the following two forms (when the path's traversal direction is ignored):

- **Type A:** $p(v_1) = v_2$, $p(v_2) = v_3$, $p(v_3) = v_4$, or
- **Type B:** $p(v_1)=p(v_3)=v_2$ and $p(v_4)=p(v_3)$.

To enumerate all paths of type $A$ it suffices to perform a DFS visit of $T$. When a vertex $v$ at depth at least $3$ is encountered, return the path $\langle v, p(v), p(p(v)), p(p(p(v))) \rangle$.
This takes $O(n)$ time overall.

To enumerate all paths of type $B$, perform a DFS visit of $T$ and when a vertex $v$ at depth at least $2$ is encountered, return all the paths of the form $\langle v, p(v), p(p(v)), u \rangle$ where $u \in C(p(p(v))) \setminus \{ p(v) \}$.
This requires time $O(n + P)$, where $P$ is the number of paths of type $B$ in $T$.

Overall you can enumerate all the paths of length $3$ in $T$ in time $O(n + P)$.

Notice that $\Omega(n)$ is a lower bound on the time needed by any algorithm since you need to read the input tree. A bad case in which $P=0$ but you still spend $\Theta(n)$ time is a star.

Comment: Thank you     Could you help with with method or link on how to find the diametrical path of a Tree

Comment: Right now I can only give the gist. But I'm sure you can find a description of how to solve that problem if you google. Anyway: Root the tree in an arbitrary vertex. Notice that there is a unique vertex of minimum depth in a diametral path $P$. Let this vertex be $v$. Then $P$ is the concatenation of two paths from $v$ to the deepest leaves in two distinct subtrees rooted in the children of $v$ (one or both of these paths might possibly be empty). Use a DFS visit to compute the length of such paths for all the nodes of $T$. This allows you to find $v$ and $P$.